# JavaScript regex auto commas with decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following JavaScript + Regex to auto add commas to a user input as they type:

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/[^-\d.]/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

This works great, but it does not work for decimals. It adds commas to the decimals, which I don't want.

I could update the code to do a check to see if there are commas after the decimal. However, I think there may be a more elegant solution with Regex.

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    var num = value
    .replace(/[^-\d.]/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var numSplit = num.split('.');
    if(numSplit.length > 1){
      num = numSplit[0] + '.' + numSplit[1].replace(/,/g, "");
    }
    return num;
  });
});
```

I've tried adding a check to first see if a `.` exists. But I did not write it correctly.

`\B(?=[^.](\d{3})+(?!\d))`

Is there a better way to do this with regex?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNOgMm

Comment: This `replace(/\D/g, "")` removes all decimal sign

Comment: Sorry, fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Apply **Regex** only to the **whole number**

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    var num = value
      .replace(/[^-\d.]/g, "")
    var numSplit = num.split('.');
    if (numSplit.length > 1) {
      num = numSplit[0]
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + numSplit[1].replace(/,/, "");
    } else {
      num = num.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
    return num;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number">
```

**Shorter Version**

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    var num = value
      .replace(/[^-\d.]/g, "")
      .replace(/^\.+/g, "")
      .replace(/\./, "x").replace(/\./g, "").replace(/x/, ".")
      
    return (/^\d+\.\d+$/.test(num))
      ? num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)$)/g, "$1,") 
      : num.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

So, with a simple replace callback you can match the decimal part
then just return it, or match the assertion for a thousands place
then return `,`.
No need to split, it just makes it more complicated.
Since you're using regex, do it all with regex.

The regex expanded:

```
   ( \. \d* )                    # (1), Decimal part
|                              # or,
   \B                            # Thousands part
   (?=
        (?: \d{3} )+
        (?! \d )
 )
```

```js
var input = "122341234.188874";
input = input.replace (/[^-\d.]/g, "" );
input = input.replace (/(\.\d*)|\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, 
  function( m, g1 ) // match, group 1
  {
    if ( g1 > "" )
      return g1;
    else
      return ",";
  }

);

console.log(input);
```

Another thing you may want to consider is to validate the
*form* after stripping invalid characters.

I believe you could do that with a
`replace (/^(?:.*?(-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))|).*$/g, "$1" );`